# Arduino keeps looping

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, programming, arduino-ide

I made a program where I give a number(4 bit) as input and four led on the breadboard lights up according to its binary. The problem is the program works all well only for (2-15) but if I give 0 or 1 as input it keeps looping and the serial monitor keeps printing that number. If I remove the "**prbline**" from the code the program works but the serial monitor only prints the input number if it is 0 or 1. Why is it like this?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int red1=2;
int red2=3;
int red3=4;
int red4=5;
int num=1; // this is the input number
char number[4];
int len;
char str3[]="000",str2[]="00",str1[]="0",str[]="0000";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(red1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red4,OUTPUT);
  itoa (num,number,2);
  len=strlen(number);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(num);
  Serial.println(number);
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.println(str);


  if(len==1){
    strcat(str3,number);
    strcpy(str,str3);
    }
  else if(len==2){
    strcat(str2,number);
    strcpy(str,str2);
    }
  else if(len==3){
    strcat(str1,number);
    strcpy(str,str1);
    }
  else {
    strcpy(str,number);
    }
  Serial.println(str); //prbline

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(str[0]=='1'){
    digitalWrite(red1,HIGH);
    }
  if(str[1]=='1'){
    digitalWrite(red2,HIGH);
    }
  if(str[2]=='1'){
    digitalWrite(red3,HIGH);
    }
  if(str[3]=='1'){
    digitalWrite(red4,HIGH);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you providing the input?

Comment: I change the value of the 'num' variable from the IDE and upload

Answer (score 1):

So many mistakes in such a short code:

- number is too short for more than 3 bit numbers (8 and higher)
- strcat is modifying first string, so all strings str1, str2, str3 are too short too
- if you want to use them more than once, it'l be adding string to them over and over.....

Basically, if you can see output from the setup over and over, it means crash and start from the reset vector.

But, the main question is why don't you use bit manipulation on num directly:

```
  digitalWrite(red1, (num & 0b1000) != 0 ); 
  digitalWrite(red2, (num & 0b0100) != 0 );
  digitalWrite(red3, (num & 0b0010) != 0 );
  digitalWrite(red4, (num & 0b0001) != 0 );
```

Or with using bit positions:

```
  digitalWrite(red1, (num & (1 << 3)) != 0 ); 
  digitalWrite(red2, (num & (1 << 2)) != 0 );
  digitalWrite(red3, (num & (1 << 1)) != 0 );
  digitalWrite(red4, (num & (1 << 0)) != 0 );
```

Bit positions little bit more readable by using macro `_BV` (which is translated to 1 << ..)

```
  digitalWrite(red1, (num & _BV(3)) != 0 ); 
  digitalWrite(red2, (num & _BV(2)) != 0 );
  digitalWrite(red3, (num & _BV(1)) != 0 );
  digitalWrite(red4, (num & _BV(0)) != 0 );
```

or more interesting macro wrapper `bit_is_set` to be more readable:

```
  digitalWrite(red1, bit_is_set(num,3)); 
  digitalWrite(red2, bit_is_set(num,2));
  digitalWrite(red3, bit_is_set(num,1));
  digitalWrite(red4, bit_is_set(num,0));
```

And, as a bonus, it can be even done in a loop:

```
byte reds[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2 }; // to preserve the same order as in the question
byte num    = 1;

void loop() {
  byte tmp = num;
  for (byte pin : reds) {
    digitalWrite(pin, tmp & 1);
    tmp >>= 1; // bit shift by one to the right (= division by 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

To add to KIIV's concise response, the line

```
Serial.println(str); //prbline
```

can be easiest created without itoa and leading zero helper strings by

```
int num = 9; // Test input 0 .. 9 ( or even 15 = 0x0F ) 
void setup() {
 char str[] = "0000";
 byte tmp = num & 0x0F; // limit to valid values 
 for (byte i=3; tmp != 0; i--, tmp >>= 1) 
   if (tmp & 0x01) str[i] = '1';
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.print(num);
Serial.print(" = ");
Serial.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting memory.

```
 if(len==1){
    strcat(str3,number);
    strcpy(str,str3);
    }
```

There is room for 3 characters in str3, however you are using strcat to add more characters.

I don't understand your technique, however this might help make it work:

```
char str3[6]="000",str2[6]="00",str1[6]="0",str[6]="0000";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it really helped me.